# How much CPU do I have left?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, cpu

My Ubuntu 16.04 server hosts 4 processes, that run every 15sec, during about 10 sec. They hence require cpu on a periodic level.
My server is a virtual machine made out of 4 cores (in fact a translation from a given amount of GHz), and I want to know how much GHz/cpu I really need in order to know, whether I can introduce another process.

My guess is that if each process requires at most X% of the cpu when running, the left cpu for another process is 400 - 4 * X.

So with 4 cores, i.e. 400%, and about 70% at maximum processing, that would leave 400 - 4 * 70 = 120% free at peak usage.

Is this estimation correct?

Added:
As a non-expert, this is obviously a scoop approach. I could get the details for all known processes, and then gather the info for the "rest".

Comment: It's complicated. If you've run top, you've probably noticed there's a bunch of other things running, too, and they'll still take up their share, but if we're talking abouts, then, sure. For a more precise answer, more precise details would be needed, which would include information about how independent your processes are, and how much of an impact they have on other processes. You'd probably also want someone with more expertise to answer than me...